# How to verify a RabbitMQ user password?

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a simple method to verify a RabbitMQ user password from command line? By *simple* I mean:

- without rabbitmq_management plugin enabled
- without extra dependencies, like ruby/python/etc. libraries not usually present on a Linux machine by default.

Comment: I've asked the RabbitMQ team to introduce such a feature at https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1576 .

Comment: Actually, it looks like normal user credentials cannot even be tested with rabbitmqadmin - it fails with "Not management user".

Answer (score 7):

`sudo rabbitmqctl authenticate_user <username> <password>`

If the password is appropriate it shows:

```
Authenticating user "username"
Success
```

If the password is wrong it shows the below:

```
Authenticating user "username"
Error: failed to authenticate user "username"
```

Comment: If you need to reset the password, just use `rabbitmqctl change_password <username> <password>`

Answer (score 3):

- There is [rabbitmqctl authenticate_user](http://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#authenticate_user)
- `rabbitmqadmin` can be used if the user has the `management` tag (which can be added temporarily)
- Alternative [authN backends](http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) have more options: LDAP tooling for the LDAP backend, curl for the HTTP backend and so on.

Comment: Ahh, dang - I was checking this on RabbitMQ on an RHEL box, which still has 3.3. Looks like `authenticate_user` was added in 3.6.5 - https://rabbitmq.docs.pivotal.io/36/relnotes/release-notes-rabbitmq3.6.5.html .

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to login with the username/password using rabbitmqadmin, although this is not included by default when installing RabbitMQ.

IMHO the simplest thing to do is write a Python script that connects to RabbitMQ, but this requires either a) the Kombu library or equivalent, or b) writing your own minimalistic AMQP client.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was is there a way to avoid both of your suggestions.

Comment: Sure, I thought that was the case. rabbitmqadmin is not the same as rabbitmq_management plugin, so I thought it worth mentioning. AKAICT your only options are to download a program that can authenticate against AMQP, or write your own implementation of AMQP's authentication protocol: http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/07/who-are-you-authentication-and-authorisation-in-rabbitmq-231/